# submit value of html table to variable in controller ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table in view:

```
#view
<%= form_tag save_table_path do %>
    <table>                         
     <% @channel_name_body.values.max_by(&:size).size.times do |i| %>
        <tr class="border">
            <% @channel_name_body.values.map { |a| a[i] }.each do |value| %>
              <td contenteditable class="border light_green"><%= value %></td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
 <%= submit_tag "save",:class => "btn btn-primary offset4" %>
<% end %>
```

I don't know what to do next to pass value of all cell in table to controller such as:

```
#controller
def save_table
  @table=params[:table] #or @row1=params[:row1]... or @col1=params[:col1]....
end
```

Edit: I found way to solve this problem, it must use js.
I don't want to use js, what about if I change to <%= text_field_tag :cell, value %> how can I get value of all cell in table ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564120/passing-edited-value-contenteditable-field-from-view-to-controller-in-rails

Comment: I don't want to use js, what about if I change to
 <td ><%= text_field_tag :cell, value %></td>

how can I get value of all cell in table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting confused with how to handle data in Rails (or any backend system)

---

**HTML**

HTML is a markup language; which means if you give it certain code, it will put various elements onto the page. The `<table>` tag is one of those elements, and has no bearing on the controller-side functionality of your app

---

**Controller Params**

HTML form params are directly related to the `form` (nothing else)

In Rails, you get the params hash ordered like this:

```
params[:form_name][:input_name]
```

---

**Your Code**

From what you've shown, it seems you have several parts missing

Firstly, you need `input` elements (to populate the params). Currently, you have:

```
<td contenteditable class="border light_green"><%= value %></td>
```

This does not create any params, as it's not an input element. It's just a value that's been outputted on the screen. What you'd need is something like:

```
<td contenteditable class="border light_green"><%= text_field_tag :cell, :value => value %></td>
```

By adding these inputs, you will give Rails the ability to populate the params hash with their values, which you can then access from your controller like this:

```
def save
    @table = params[:form_name][:cell][0]
end
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: it don't send all params, it just send only params cell[0]
example: my table 
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
table = params[:cell][0] > table =1

table = params[:cell][1] > table =nill

Comment: Hmmm well maybe we can change the table cells to something like this: `<%= text_field_tag "#cell_{i}", :value => value %>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= text_field_tag "table[cell#{index}]", value %>
```

On form submit it will give you values like `params[:table][:cell1], params[:table][:cell2]` and so on...

Hope this helps..